# Silverlight performance testing

Tags: silverlight, performance, testing

My company has a Silverlight app running in an asp.net page.  Does anyone have any recommendations on any performance testing tools for how the app will perform within the client's browser? Any tools that could simulate different PC configurations (Memory, CPU, etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

VS 2010 can now profile Silverlight

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seema/archive/2010/01/28/pdc-vs2010-profiling-silverlight-4.aspx

However, I was not able to get this approach running (yet) in Windows 7 64-bit

[Profiling Silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310853/profiling-silverlight-4)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Eqatec](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/Home.aspx) for profiling. It is awesome.

You can profile any .net app with it, including Silverlight, Silverlight on WP7, ASP.net, Windows Forms, WPF etc.

Answer (score 0):

For simulation of different HW configuration, you could try test within virtual machine, or you can disable CPU cores and undeclock you CPU in BIOS and you can disable specific size of RAM in Windows configuration.