# Profiling Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, profiler

I have a Silverlight page that displays100+ user controls in a `ScrollViewer` (around 50% of the controls are visible at once, depending on browser resolution).

When I scroll using the ScrollViewer, scrolling is sluggish and one of my 4 CPU cores goes to 100% (and stays there as long as I keep moving a scrollbar).

I wanted to profile the application to better understand where the time is being spent following the instructions on this [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seema/archive/2010/01/28/pdc-vs2010-profiling-silverlight-4.aspx).  Like one of the commenters, I get the error

> No Call Tree Data Is Available.

when I open the .vsp file.

I run my profiling session with this batch file:

```
call vsperfclrenv /sampleon 
set CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1
set CORECLR_PROFILER=%COR_PROFILER%
call vsperfcmd /start:sample /output:myProfile.vsp
call vsperfcmd /launch:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" /timer:100000
echo Browse to http://localhost:9567/MyTestPage.aspx#/Home
call vsperfcmd /shutdown

Echo Before viewing, turn on the symbols server in VS2010 through: Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->Symbols-->check microsoft symbols server.
Echo Open .vsp file in VS2010
```

One blog commentor suggested the problem is due to a 64-bit version of vsperfcmd.  While I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, vsperfcmd suggests that it's an x86 build:

> vsperfcmd
>
> Microsoft (R) VSPerf Command Version 10.0.40219 x86

What am I missing to profile my user code?

Comment: Have you checked of the profiler has been loaded by the CLR - it should add an entry to the Application Event Log; the CLR2/4 runtime does this for normal .NET application so I am assuming it does the same for Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this in an administrator console window - I have recently noticed that I can't profile (code coverage) silverlight applications unless I am running under an Administrator account i.e. starting a console window with "run as administrator"